# VS code access denied when executing user input file in terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Here is what i tried so far, but after running the program, this shows some error;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){



    int number; 
  
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&number)
    printf("The number is %d",number);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I ran the program it shows me this error

```
Program 'hello.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:59
+ cd "d:\c\" ; if ($?) { gcc hello.c -o hello } ; if ($?) { .\hello }
+                                                           ~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:59
+ cd "d:\c\" ; if ($?) { gcc hello.c -o hello } ; if ($?) { .\hello }
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. There are a couple of things that may cause this error.

1. MinGW is not installed properly. Install properly if not installed.
   Click [here](https://www.eclipse.org/4diac/documentation/html/installation/minGW.html#:%7E:text=Setting%20up%20MinGW-w64%201%20Install%20MinGW-w64.%20MinGW-w64%20comprises,the%20make%20executable.%20...%204%20Next%20steps.%20).
2. If your code doesn't involve taking any input from the user and giving the output properly, and it says "access denied" when the code requires user input, it is probably due to the antivirus you are using. I have the same problem, I discovered that my antivirus "McAfee" caused this problem and I uninstalled it. The code worked perfectly. But Windows Defender doesn't cause this problem, hence I am now using Windows Defender to protect my pc. If you don't trust Windows Defender and you really think that the antivirus you are using now is necessary, don't go for this.